Seagate Ironwolf 4TB drives reverting APM settings on Ubuntu 22LTS after upgrade from 20LTS in RAID-5 array
I recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20LTS to Ubuntu 22LTS, and I've encountered an issue with my RAID-5 array consisting of four Seagate Ironwolf 4TB hard drives (from /dev/sda to /dev/sdd). These drives are going into standby mode unexpectedly. Before the upgrade, the drives operated continuously without entering standby, which is crucial for RAID environments.
To prevent the drives from going into standby, I've tried setting the Advanced Power Management (APM) and standby timer using hdparm as follows:
hdparm -B 255 /dev/sd[a-d] (to disable APM)
hdparm -S 0 /dev/sd[a-d] (to disable the standby timer)

However, these settings do not persist, and the APM value keeps reverting to 20 after some time, causing the drives to enter standby mode again.
I've checked for any system services or power management settings that might be overriding these hdparm configurations but haven't found anything conclusive yet. The issue seems to have started after the upgrade to Ubuntu 22LTS.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or has suggestions on how to prevent the APM and standby settings from being overridden? Are there any specific system settings or services in Ubuntu 22LTS that could be affecting the power management of hard drives in a RAID-5 array?

Could you please elaborate? I would mark this as solution if it works. I'm currently trying openSeaChest for Seagate drives.
